# Use outer instead of expand.grid

Tags: r

I'm looking for as much speed as possible and staying in base to do what `expand.grid` does. I have used `outer` for similar purposes in the past to create a vector; something like this:

```
v <- outer(letters, LETTERS, paste0)
unlist(v[lower.tri(v)])
```

Benchmarking has shown me that `outer` can be drastically faster than `expand.grid` but this time I want to create two columns just like `expand.grid` (all possible combos for 2 vectors) but my methods with `outer` do not benchmark as fast with outer this time.

I'm hoping to take 2 vectors and create every possible combo as two columns as fast as possible (I think `outer` may be the route but am wide open to any base method.

Here's the `expand.grid` method and `outer` method.

```
dat <- cbind(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)

expand.grid(seq_len(nrow(dat)), seq_len(ncol(dat)))

FOO <- function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep=":")
x <- outer(seq_len(nrow(dat)), seq_len(ncol(dat)), FOO)
apply(do.call("rbind", strsplit(x, ":")), 2, as.integer)
```

The microbenchmarking shows `outer` is slower:

```
#     expr      min        lq    median        uq      max
# EXPAND.G  812.743  838.6375  894.6245  927.7505 27029.54
#    OUTER 5107.871 5198.3835 5329.4860 5605.2215 27559.08
```

I think my `outer` use is slow because I don't know how to use `outer` to directly create a length 2 vector that I can `do.call('rbind'` together. I have to slow `paste` and slow split.  How can I do this with `outer` (or other methods in `base`) in a way that's faster than `expand grid`?

**EDIT:
Adding the microbenchmark results.**

**

```
Unit: microseconds
      expr     min       lq  median      uq       max
1   ERNEST  34.993  39.1920  52.255  57.854 29170.705
2     JOHN  13.997  16.3300  19.130  23.329   266.872
3 ORIGINAL 352.720 372.7815 392.377 418.738 36519.952
4    TOMMY  16.330  19.5960  23.795  27.061  6217.374
5  VINCENT 377.447 400.3090 418.505 451.864 43567.334
```

**

[image]

Comment: Tyler, do you mind adding my method to the benchmark list?  It should come in half the speed of the fastest one you have here.

Comment: Yes just did.  It is indeed the fastest.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `rep.int`:

```
expand.grid.alt <- function(seq1,seq2) {
  cbind(rep.int(seq1, length(seq2)),
        c(t(matrix(rep.int(seq2, length(seq1)), nrow=length(seq2)))))
}

expand.grid.alt(seq_len(nrow(dat)), seq_len(ncol(dat)))
```

In my computer is like 6 times faster than `expand.grid`.

Comment: I was very skeptical but it is very fast.  Nice response.  I guess outer wasn't the approach i should have been taking.  I posted the microbenchmarking results on a WIn 7 machine above.

Comment: @TylerRinker Beware, there was a bug in my function! The `nrow` argument was wrong. I've fixed it now.

Comment: @ErnestA I added a parenthesis to the far right of the last line of code then had to add some more text before the edit could be submitted.

Answer (score 18):

The documentation for `rep.int` isn't quite complete.  It isn't just fastest in the most common case because you can pass vectors for the times argument, just like with `rep`.  You can use it straightforward for both sequences reducing the time another 40% or so over Tommy's.

```
expand.grid.jc <- function(seq1,seq2) {
    cbind(Var1 = rep.int(seq1, length(seq2)), 
    Var2 = rep.int(seq2, rep.int(length(seq1),length(seq2))))
}
```

Comment: in it's current state your code throws up an error.  I think it's missing a parenthesis somewhere but I couldn't figure out where.

Comment: +1 Awesome! It *shouldn't* be faster than mine, but it certainly is :-) Apparently, `rep` needs to improve how it handles the `each` argument...

Comment: yes Tommy, it should... I actually think that expand.grid uses something like what I wrote internally... it's just slow because of error checking and robustness.

Comment: What if we just have one list to pass as variable and want all possible combinations ? e.g. expand.grid_jc(input_list)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you have a list with two vectors in it then you could just use do.call(expand.grid.jc, myList). Otherwise, I'm not sure how the question makes sense. Perhaps expand it to a full CrossValidated question?

Answer (score 6):

@ErnestA has a great solution well worthy of the answer tick!

...it could be marginally faster though:

```
expand.grid.alt2 <- function(seq1,seq2) {
  cbind(Var1=rep.int(seq1, length(seq2)), Var2=rep(seq2, each=length(seq1)))
}

s1=seq_len(2000); s2=seq_len(2000)
system.time( for(i in 1:10) expand.grid.alt2(s1, s2) ) # 1.58
system.time( for(i in 1:10) expand.grid.alt(s1, s2) )  # 1.75
system.time( for(i in 1:10) expand.grid(s1, s2) )      # 2.46
```

Comment: Very nice, definitely a speed boost over Ernest's.  +1  I am going to keep the check on Ernest though this is faster because I've already given the check and I feel funny about reassigning.  It would make me feel at complete ease if you based your response on his answer :)  May I ask if you did?

Comment: @TylerRinker - Yes I did. So you can feel at complete ease now ;-)

Comment: @Tommy I went to great lengths to avoid `rep(... each=)` because I assumed it'd be slower. In fact, it isn't.

Comment: @TylerRinker Feel free to uncheck my answer as there are other solutions that run faster. No problem at all!

Answer (score 3):

You can create the two columns separately.

```
library(microbenchmark)
n <- nrow(dat)
m <- ncol(dat)
f1 <- function()   expand.grid(1:n, 1:m)
f2 <- function()   
  data.frame( 
    Var1 = as.vector(outer( 1:n, rep(1,m) )),
    Var2 = as.vector(outer( rep(1,n), 1:m ))
  )
microbenchmark( f1, f2, times=1e6 )
# Unit: nanoseconds
#   expr min  lq median  uq    max
# 1   f1  70 489    490 559 168458
# 2   f2  70 489    490 559 168597
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You solved my outer problem  and the learning was terrific.  Ernest's approach is very quick, much quicker than the outer approach.