# Multiplying two different lists objects in R

Tags: r

I have read [Multiplying Combinations of a list of lists in R.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552387/multiplying-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists-in-r) But i can't still apply it on my case.

I have two different lists in R:

```
x <- list(matrix(1:4,nrow=2), matrix(5:8, nrow=2))
y <- list(matrix(c(1,0,0,1), nrow=2), matrix(c(0,1,0,1), nrow=2) )
```

I want to multiply the 1st element of `x` with the 1st element of `y`; 
the 2nd element of `x` with the 2nd element of `y`.  That is,

```
x[[1]] * y[[1]]
x[[2]] * y[[2]]
```

But I don't want to write one line code for each element since I have 100 elements in each list.

Comment: See either `?mapply` or `?Map`.

Comment: I'm not given the ability to answer, but another possibility is to use the `purrr` package with the following line: `map2(x, y, function(x, y) x*y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` as shown below:

```
Map('*',x,y)
```

Output of the above code is shown below:

```
> Map('*',x,y)
  [[1]]
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    4

 [[2]]
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    6    8
```

**OR**

You can use `unlist` to unlist list and multiple list together:

```
Listxy <- list(unlist(x)*unlist(y))
Listxy
[[1]]
[1] 1 0 0 4 0 6 0 8
```